# databasefactory.cs not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, enterprise-library

I am using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary in my application. I have added Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll as reference and I can see DatabaseFactory if I object browse Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll. But still I am getting databasefactory.cs not found error. Can anyone please help.

Web.config code:

```
<add name="ExternalFile" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" filePath="dataConfiguration.config" >
```

Comment: Does this match the one in the GAC?

Comment: Is it actually not present in GAC.... I looked at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC, am I looking in right place...

Comment: I'd add the one you want to the GAC and then make sure your app.config and web.config match the public key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is solved... I was importing dlls from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin folder but I also had same dlls in bin folder pf application, both of different versions. I deleted the dlls from application bin folder and copied dlls from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin" to application bin. This solved error. Thanks for help........